# Solution verification: Determine for which values ​of $\alpha$ the function is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Find the values $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the function $(x,y) \mapsto (1-xy)^{\alpha}$ is integrable on $(0,1)\times (0,1) $.

My attempt:

By Fubini's theorem we can write
$$\int_{(0,1)\times(0,1)} (1-xy)^{\alpha}dxdy= \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{1}(1-xy)^{\alpha}$$

Taking $u = 1-xy$, we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{1}(1-xy)^{\alpha}=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\int_{1}^{1-y}u^{\alpha}du$$

If $\alpha \neq -1$ then
$$\int_{1}^{1-y}u^{\alpha}du= \frac{(1-y)^{\alpha +1}-1}{\alpha +1}$$
and therefore
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\int_{1}^{1-y}u^{\alpha}du=\frac{1}{\alpha+1} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^{\alpha+1}}{y}dy -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\right)$$

Since the function $\frac{1}{y}$ is not integrable in $(0,1)$ then the function $(x,y) \mapsto (1-xy)^{\alpha}$ is not integrable if $\alpha \neq -1$. Therefore it is only integrable when $\alpha=-1$

My solution doesn't convince me, but I don't see if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Your argument fails.  When $\alpha=-1$, the last expression isn't even defined, because you've divided by $0$.  When $\alpha\neq0$ the argument is invalid.  You can only conclude that the integral doesn't exist if you show that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^{\alpha+1}}{y}dy$ exists.  You can't conclude anything if you've written the integral as the difference of two divergent integrals.  Indeed, when $\geq0$, the integrand is continuous, and the integral exists.

Comment: Well yes, clearly that expression will not be defined when $\alpha =-1$. So all of this was done assuming that $\alpha \neq -1$. @saulspatz

Comment: And then it's incorrect, for the reason I stated.

Comment: You say I divide by $0$, but I didn't actually do that. @saulspatz

Comment: Look at the part of my comment that starts "When $\alpha\neq-1$"

Comment: Your comment doesn't start with that anywhere ... @saulspatz

Comment: Sorry that's a typo in the comment.  Where it says "when $\alpha\neq0$" it should say "when $alpha\neq-1$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it's integrable if $\alpha \ge 0$, as the function is continuous and bounded on the whole region of integration. So your argument definitely has a problem.

Things go wrong here:

> and therefore
> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\int_{1}^{1-y}u^{\alpha}du=\frac{1}{\alpha+1} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^{\alpha+1}}{y}dy -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\right)$$

The correct statement is
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\int_{1}^{1-y}u^{\alpha}du=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^{\alpha+1} - 1}{(\alpha + 1)y}dy
$$
You can't split up the fraction because the numerator and denominator both go to zero near $y = 0$. Doing the Taylor series on the integrand around $0$ shows us that the integrand remains finite there regardless of $\alpha$, so the behavior near $0$ doesn't affect integrability.

However, if $\alpha < -1$, then the exponent of $(1-y)$ is negative. The integrand blows up near $y = 1$, and it will do so in a non-integrable way if $\alpha + 1 \le -1$. Thus, the function is integrable provided that $\alpha > -2$.